# Confidence interval crosses 0 but statistical significance at p < 0.05 using robust post hoc tests, any explanation?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, post-hoc, robust

I have 12 groups so 66 contrasts, though I'm only interested in 6 of them, I'm using the mcppb20() function from Rand Wilcox's WRS package in R. I'm using 5000 bootstrap samples as suggested and 0.2 trimmed means.

For the 6 p-values I'm interested in, there are some values where p is < 0.05 but the CI crosses 0.

Any idea on how to interpret this? Been going through old books but haven't found something as of yet.